# Spring interceptor not working for partial REST endpoints

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, interceptor

I have a Spring Boot application with REST endpoints defined like this

```
/usermanagement/v1/access/ldap
/usermanagement/v1/access/db
```

I have created a Spring Interceptor to intercept all incoming request with following pattern

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
   registry.addInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/usermanagement/v1/**");
}
```

**RequestInterceptor**

```
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
        throws Exception {
        System.out.println("This is Post Handling the request");
    }
}
```

This interceptor works only if client accesses the complete endpoint i.e

> /usermanagement/v1/access/ldap

In case a partial endpoint is accessed,

> /usermanagement/v1/access

interceptor is not called and a 404 is returned to the client.

Is there a way to change this behavior? The reason I am doing this is because I don't want to expose specific endpoints but common endpoints and make internal calls to services and return result through common endpoints.

Comment: did you define any resource access on `/usermanagement/v1/access`?

Comment: @HerrDerb No, I have not but since it matches the pattern to be intercepted, interceptor should get called.

Comment: Are you doing  `preHandling` or `postHandling` in your `RequestInterceptor`? And what is suposed to be returned with `/usermanagement/v1/access`? the ldap or the db resource? I get the feeling that you would not need an interceptor at all.

Comment: @HerrDerb yes I have empty implementations of them in my interceptor. I am using `/usermanagement/v1/access` as a common endpoint. After which request will be parsed and forwarded internally to the corresponding service depending upon the values in header and body of the request.

Comment: If you have empty implementations of the handler, they of course don't handle nothing. So the request will be forwarded to `/usermanagement/v1/access` which is not defined therefor Spring will give you a `404`, which is correct. Or did I misunderstand something? Can you add the source of your handler maybe?

Comment: @HerrDerb I have added the code for interceptor. But interceptor gets called when accessing the complete endpoint in spite of methods being empty.

Comment: interestingly, using wildcard without the base (i.e., addPathPatterns("/**") ) does get to the interceptor methods

Comment: to be specific, it gets to the preHandle method

Comment: @tmart that is true but then it gets called for every request. That can't be acceptable.

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary yes I don't propose it as a solution, just wondering why the wildcard works if in root and not after the base path. Trying to figure out why

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong method. Try using `afterCompletion` instead of  `postHandle`

```
new HandlerInterceptor() {

        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        //This is called before handeling any request
        }

        @Override
        public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        //This is called after successfully handeling a request. It will not be called in case of an exception
        }

        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        //This will always be called after a request, even in case of an exception
        }
}
```

With a request to a undefined endpoint `/usermanagement/v1/access` Spring will throw an exception. Therefor it never will enter `postHandle`.

Comment: None of the method is getting called. Did you try this at your end?

Comment: I was looking for this one only.Thanks :)